# How can I not disable my theme when I want to upload a new version of it?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am creating my own theme but I frequently make changes. When I try to upload a new version of the theme it sometimes ***ignores the changes*** or I sometimes get ***two themes*** or on the file system the ***theme directory has two themes***.

I can't pin down when and where it doesn't work but uploading a new zip for me doesn't work. The changes are not applied.

The only way I've been able to get it to work is:

1. Activate another theme (deactivating my theme)
2. Delete my theme
3. Upload the new version of my theme
4. Activate my theme

Is it possible with WordPress to simply update my theme with one step, without deactivating it?

1. Upload new theme and it's applied

Comment: Have you tried the [Update Theme and Plugins from Zip File](https://wordpress.org/plugins/update-theme-and-plugins-from-zip-file/) plugin?

Comment: @kero I haven't seen that before. That looks like it does what I was hoping for

Comment: Here are two comments from the plugin page, "Although it allows updates from zip files, it is not technically an update. This plugin actually deactivates/uninstalls the old plugin and installs the new one, without triggering the 'upgrader_process_complete' hook." And the next one, "...can you add an auto reactivate option?" So it look likes the only thing this plugin does is deactivate and delete my current theme first.